# Selecting from the CjK languages on the iPhone

Tags: ios

I've localized my application in several languages and they all work fine except, I don't know how to test in Chinese. I have made all my `.xib` files `zh` for Chinese Simplified but don't know where Chinese is on the iPhone Language settings. I can't tell the difference between Chinese, Korean, Japanese or any other similar far eastern languages therefore, I can't set my simulator or iPhone accordingly to test it. Is there someone who can guide me to the appropriate language setting on the iPhone please?

Comment: How did u localize in these languages if you cannot even google for the localized language name?

Answer (score 9):

If you are asking which is which:

```
繁體中文  - Chinese (Traditional)
简体中文  - Chinese (Simplified)
日本語    - Japanese
한국어     - Korean
```

Answer (score 1):

iPhone apps already use UTF-8 by default which is a multi-byte character encoding for UNICODE.

See a nice explanation of this type of encoding [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

Answer (score 1):

To Eric.

"한국의 - Korean ", It is wrong.

한국'어' is right, not 한국'의'.

Comment: You are right, though the sampling of characters should have been enough to differentiate at least Korean from the rest. Japanese is particularly tricky of course, given the mixture of scripts in use.